# Web scraping: How do I handle euro signs?

Tags: xpath, screen-scraping, euro

So I'm trying to scrape prices of a product on a website, and their HTML looks like this:

`<div class="pricing_price">€12.99</div>`

Now I've wrote a xpath query that gets price, and it returns a string like this:

`â‚¬Â 12.99`.

If possible, I would like to just get the `12.99`. What are my options? Should I use regular expressions? Or are there better/easier solutions?

Comment: Looks like a charset problem. Make sure you're parsing in the same charset as the document is displayed in.

Comment: I cant find any mentions of `utf8` or something differently on the page

Comment: How do you parse the document? XPath works on a tree model with Unicode characters created by an XML or HTML parser so the problem is not with changing the XPath expression, you need to make sure the parser you use parses the document with the encoding/character set it has been written with.

Comment: So if the page has `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />` I should do the same and it works?